# Biblatex descending order of references with labels not working

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I just downloaded TeX Live 2016 and it broke my CV which had my publications (single .bib file) divided by type. It used to print

```
Refereed Conference Publications
[C1]

Miscellaneous
[M5]
[M4]
[M3]
[M2]
[M1]
```

However after the update, the numbering was all over the place. Something like

```
Refereed Conference Publications
[C3]

Miscellaneous
[M13]
[M12]
[M11]
[M10]
[M9]
```

I was looking online and saw that they changed how `\printbibliography` works. Now, we are not allowed to put the `prefixnumber` as an option.

After looking in this site, I found this [question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226695/biblatex-descending-order-of-references-but-multiple-lists-starting-from-highest). This works for me now, but I am not able to print the labels, i.e.

```
Refereed Conference Publications
[1]

Miscellaneous
[5]
[4]
[3]
[2]
[1]
```

Is there a way to make it work with the labels?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:** Here is a MWE

```
%% pdflatex MWE
%% biber MWE
%% pdflatex MWE
%% pdflatex MWE
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,roman]{moderncv}       

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.5cm}

\name{Miguel}{Velez}

\usepackage[defernumbers=true,sorting=none,backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}

\AtDataInput{%
  \csnumgdef{entrycount:\therefsection:\thefield{entrytype}}{%
    \csuse{entrycount:\therefsection:\thefield{entrytype}}+1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}    
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\csuse{entrycount:\therefsection:\thefield{entrytype}}+1-#1\relax}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{% label format from numeric.bbx
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}% layout parameters from moderncvstyleclassic.sty
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{\hintscolumnwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \leftmargin\labelwidth%
      \advance\leftmargin\labelsep}%
      \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}  

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}  

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Publications}
%\newrefcontext[labelprefix=C]
\nocite{WLS:ICSE76}%,VS:IUST16,VS:CCSC15,VS:MSRP15,V:SUMMA15,VGS:IUST14}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Refereed Conference     Publications},type=inproceedings,resetnumbers=true]
%\newrefcontext[labelprefix=M]
\nocite{VS:IUST16,VS:CCSC15,VS:MSRP15,V:SUMMA15,VGS:IUST14}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Miscellaneous},
type=misc,resetnumbers=true]

\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2:** Here is the .bib file used in the MWE

```
 @inproceedings{WLS:ICSE76,
 author = {Wulf, Wm. A. and London, Ralph L. and Shaw, Mary},
 title = {An Introduction to the Construction and Verification of Alphard Programs},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the 2Nd International Conference on Software Engineering},
 series = {ICSE '76},
 year = {1976},
 location = {San Francisco, California, USA},
 pages = {390--},
 url = {http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=800253.807708},
 acmid = {807708},
 publisher = {IEEE Computer Society Press},
 address = IEEEAddr,
}

@misc{VS:IUST16,
 author = {Velez, Miguel and Sawin, Jason},
 title = {Improving the Efficiency of CHA through Parallelization},
 howpublished = {Poster. Inquiry at St. Thomas},
 month = {May},
 year = {2016},
}

@misc{VS:CCSC15,
 author = {Velez, Miguel and Sawin, Jason},
 title = {Faster {WAH} Compression Querying through the Use of Metadata},
 howpublished = {Poster. Consortium for Computing Sciences in Colleges Midwest Region},
 year = {2015},
 note = {{1$^{st}$} place Discovery Track},
}

@misc{VS:MSRP15,
 author = {Velez, Miguel and Solar-Lezama, Armando},
 title = {Simpler Implementation of {Sketches} through Enhanced Expressiveness},
 howpublished = {Poster. MIT Summer Research Poster Session},
 year = {2015},
}

@misc{V:SUMMA15,
 author = {Velez, Miguel},
 title = {Current and Future Relationships Between Robots and Humans},
 howpublished = {Summa Cum Laude Paper},
 month = {April},
 year = {2015},
}

@misc{VGS:IUST14,
 author = {Velez, Miguel and Gittins, Peter and Sawin, Jason},
 title = {Extending {SMILES} to Encode Reaction Mechanisms},
 howpublished = {Poster. Inquiry at St. Thomas},
 month = {May},
 year = {2014},
}
```

Comment: I just uploaded a MWE and how I compile it. Thanks!

Comment: Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1):

If you add the following code in the preamble, this should solve your problem. **However, it is not possible to cite correctly the entries**. You will get wrong negative numbers when you cite the references.

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\blx@printbibliography}
  {\blx@bibliography\blx@tempa}
  {\setcounter{bibitemtotal}{0}%
   \begingroup
   \def\do##1{\stepcounter{bibitemtotal}}%
   \dolistloop{\blx@tempa}%
   \endgroup
   \blx@bibliography\blx@tempa}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcounter{bibitemtotal}
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\value{bibitemtotal}+1-#1\relax}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{\printfield{labelprefix}\printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

Then you can just use the following to print the bibliography with your fileters:

```
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=B]
\printbibliography[type=book,resetnumbers=true]

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=J]
\printbibliography[type=article,resetnumbers=true]

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=C]
\printbibliography[type=inproceedings,resetnumbers=true]
```

**Edit 1:**

The full minimal example is here:

```
%% pdflatex MWE
%% biber MWE
%% pdflatex MWE
%% pdflatex MWE
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber, 
    style=numeric,
    giveninits=true,
    maxcitenames=99,
    maxbibnames=99,
    sorting=ydnt,
    defernumbers=true,
    isbn=false,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}


\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\blx@printbibliography}
  {\blx@bibliography\blx@tempa}
  {\setcounter{bibitemtotal}{0}%
   \begingroup
   \def\do##1{\stepcounter{bibitemtotal}}%
   \dolistloop{\blx@tempa}%
   \endgroup
   \blx@bibliography\blx@tempa}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcounter{bibitemtotal}
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\value{bibitemtotal}+1-#1\relax}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{\printfield{labelprefix}\printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}


\begin{document}

\cite{A01} \cite{B02} \cite{C03}

\nocite{*}

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=B]
\printbibliography[title={Books},type=book,resetnumbers=true]

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=J]
\printbibliography[title={Journals},type=article,resetnumbers=true]

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=C]
\printbibliography[title={Conferences},type=inproceedings,resetnumbers=true]

\end{document}
```

And the .bib file used here is:

```
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}

@article{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  journal = {Journal B},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}

@inproceedings{C03,
  author = {Cesar, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Copter},
  booktitle = {Conference C},
}

@inproceedings{D04,
  author = {Diocleziano, D.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {De rerum naturae},
  booktitle = {Conference D},
}

@inproceedings{E04,
  author = {Eloise, E.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Evidence},
  booktitle = {Conference E},
}
```

The resulting pdf is the following.
[image: Resulting pdf after compilation.]

Comment: Instead of patching `\blx@printbibliography` you may want to use the `\AtBeginBibliography` and `\AtEveryBibitem` hooks.

Comment: @moewe I edited with the full MWE. How would be the alternative code if I don't want to patch `\blx@printbibliography`?

Comment: I actually thought something else would work, but `\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \setcounter{bibitemtotal}{0}%
  \begingroup
  \def\do#1{\stepcounter{bibitemtotal}}%
  \dolistloop{\blx@tempa}%
  \endgroup}` (modulo line breaks) is the closest I got without restructuring the code completely.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to replicate the desired behavior with you code in the MWE that I posted in the question. It am able to replicate your pdf with your MWE, but not with the one provided in the question.