# Reverse numbering biblatex 3.3+ with labelprefix and need for citation

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

I want to obtain different reference lists with reverse numbering order with prefix on the numbers, such as:

Books

[B3] Author, A., "Title1", 2016

[B2] Author, B., "Title2", 2016

[B1] Author, C., "Title3", 2015

Journals

[J2] Author, D., "Title4", 2016

[J1] Author, E., "Title5", 2014

and so on.

I had the following code that worked:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex, 
    style=numeric,
    firstinits=true,
    maxcitenames=99,
    maxbibnames=99,
    sorting=ydnt,
    defernumbers=true,
    isbn=false,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{publications.bib}

% Definition of asterisk
\newtoggle{bib@asterisk}
\DeclareEntryOption{asterisk}[true]{\settoggle{bib@asterisk}{#1}}

% Reverse ordering for numbers
\AtDataInput{%
  \csnumgdef{entrycount:\strfield{prefixnumber}}{%
    \csuse{entrycount:\strfield{prefixnumber}}+1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}    
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\csuse{entrycount:\strfield{prefixnumber}}+1-#1\relax%
  \iftoggle{bib@asterisk}%
    {\textbf{*}}%
    {}%
  }

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Books},type=books,prefixnumbers={B}]
\printbibliography[title={Journals},type=article,prefixnumbers={J}]
\end{document}
```

After the last update of biblatex, I have troubles in replicating the same result that I had. Apparently prefixnumbers are deprecated, and they are enforcing me to use biber instead of bibtex.

The new code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber, 
    style=numeric,
    firstinits=true,
    maxcitenames=99,
    maxbibnames=99,
    sorting=ydnt,
    defernumbers=true,
    isbn=false,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{publications.bib}

\AtDataInput{%
  \xifinlistcs{\thefield{entrykey}}{entrylist:\therefsection}{}{%
    \listcsxadd{entrylist:\therefsection}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
    \csnumgdef{entrycount:\therefsection}{%
      \csuse{entrycount:\therefsection}+1}}}

% Print the labelnumber as the total number of entries in the
% current refsection, minus the actual labelnumber, plus one
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}    
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\csuse{entrycount:\therefsection}+1-#1\relax}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=B]
\printbibliography[type=book,resetnumbers]

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=J]
\printbibliography[type=article,resetnumbers]

\end{document}
```

but what I get instead is something like

Books

[B5] Author, A., "Title1", 2016

[B4] Author, B., "Title2", 2016

[B3] Author, C., "Title3", 2015

Journals

[J5] Author, D., "Title4", 2016

[J4] Author, E., "Title5", 2014

**Notice that I need also to cite the references, so I cannot use tricks like etaremune or similar**.
Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the purpose of such a numbering system? I can't see any value in it for the reader.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I suppose it is for a CV or a list of publications. See also [Biblatex descending order of references with labels not working](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327408/35864)

Comment: It is for CV/Publications list. I have found some solutions, but none of them is able to cite correctly the references. For example if you have:

Books
[B3] ...
[B2] ...
[B1] ...

Journals
[J2] ...
[J1] ...

and you want to cite them, with the regular \cite command, you get something like [J-3] [C-1].

Comment: @moewe thank you for the link, but it still does not solve the problem. I provided my solution that works with TeX Live 2016, but I still don't know how to solve the issue with the negative references whenever you try to cite the entries in a text.

Comment: I didn't say it would solve your problem, it was just so the questions would appear linked in the sidebar.

Comment: But maybe if you use the `totcount` package you can get a two-pass solution. (The problem right now is that you count in the bibliography, but if you cite the bibliography hasn't yet been printed and thus the counter doesn't have the right value).

Comment: How would that look like? I am not familiar with the `totcount` package

Answer (score 3):

Imho something like this could work: It counts the books and articles separatly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric,
    giveninits=true,
    maxcitenames=99,
    maxbibnames=99,
    sorting=ydnt,
    defernumbers=true,
    isbn=false,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\AtDataInput[book]{%
 \xifinlistcs{\thefield{entrykey}}{entrylist:\therefsection}{}{%
  \listcsxadd{entrylist:\therefsection}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  \csnumgdef{bookentrycount:\therefsection}{%
      \csuse{bookentrycount:\therefsection}+1}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{labelnumber}{\mkbibbookdesc{#1}}

\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibbookdesc}[1]{%
   B\number\numexpr\csuse{bookentrycount:\therefsection}+1-#1\relax}

\AtDataInput[article]{%
 \xifinlistcs{\thefield{entrykey}}{entrylist:\therefsection}{}{%
  \listcsxadd{entrylist:\therefsection}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  \csnumgdef{articleentrycount:\therefsection}{%
      \csuse{articleentrycount:\therefsection}+1}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{labelnumber}{\mkbibarticledesc{#1}}

\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibarticledesc}[1]{%
   J\number\numexpr\csuse{articleentrycount:\therefsection}+1-#1\relax}

\begin{document}

\cite{iliad} \cite{aksin,herrmann}, \cite{augustine}, \cite{aristotle:anima}

\printbibliography[type=book,resetnumbers]

\printbibliography[type=article,resetnumbers]

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Attention

This will not work if the bib has entries of type `@set` and one of the articles or books are part of this set. In this case the code will count the article but not show it in the bibliography.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working with TeXLive 2016. What I actually get is that only one element per type is shown in the references, plus, the references to the Journals (the one produced by the second `\printbibliography`) is always zero when cited in the text. I don't know why.

Comment: My example works fine for me on a current texlive, and also on a current miktex which has already the next biblatex.  If you did something different you should show it.

Comment: What is your current texlive? On Linux it works fine also for me, but the most up-to-date version of texlive on Linux is not the 2016 there, it is the 2015. The problem boils down to the version of biblatex, which from 3.3+ presents this problem. What is the version of that you are using?

Comment: My "current texlive" is current. It is a texlive 2016 updated regularly. My miktex is up-to-date too. If you test the example make sure to delete the auxiliary files, sometimes some older labels survive in the aux-file.

Comment: Actually, now I managed to make it work. Thanks. However, I have another question. What if I want to filter out some of the entries, and separate them, like "submitted" and "accepted" papers, for example by means of writing `\printbibliography[type=article,notkeyword=submitted,resetnumbers]` and `\printbibliography[type=article,keyword=submitted,resetnumbers]`

Comment: Well in theory you can count everything, e.g. by using one of the hooks at the begin of every bibitem, store the values in the aux and reuse them in the next run. But writing this code is not something I want to do in my free time. Why don't you add the labels manually to the bib? That's probably much faster than trying to find an automatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the solutions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66851/29103) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22770/29103), we can use

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric,
    firstinits=true,
    maxcitenames=99,
    maxbibnames=99,
    sorting=ydnt,
    defernumbers=true,
    isbn=false,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{publications.bib}

% Reverse publication list numbering
% Count total number of entries in each refsection
\makeatletter
\defbibenvironment{counter}
  {\renewcommand{\blx@driver}[1]{}}
  {}
  {\csnumgdef{entrycount}{%
      \csuse{entrycount}+1}}
\makeatother

% Print the labelnumber as the total number of entries in the
% current refsection, minus the actual labelnumber, plus one
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\csuse{entrycount}+1-#1\relax}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=B]
\printbibliography[env=counter,type=book,heading=none]
\printbibliography[type=book]

\csnumgdef{entrycount}{0}
\nocite{*}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=J]
\printbibliography[env=counter,type=article,heading=none]
\printbibliography[type=article]
\end{document}
```

This should be flexible enough for you to use any other ways to classify all references, such as category, keyword, etc.

Comment: However, any citation in other places to these entries will be messed in some way. Help is welcome to fix citation.