# Biblatex / biber reverse numbering w/ keyword filtering

Tags: biblatex, biber, sorting, keywords

I'm struggling with the (popular) biblatex change where the 2016 upgrade stopped reverse labeling from working. Someone has provided a solution for filtering by type [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327408/biblatex-descending-order-of-references-with-labels-not-working) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329262/reverse-numbering-biblatex-3-3-with-labelprefix-and-need-for-citation). [This solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97622/reverse-numbering-in-biblatex-bibliography-with-different-categories) claims to work for keyword filtering, but not the reverse numbering. Below is my MWE, which does not produced the desired result, which should look like:

```
Foo
[F2] x y. “b”. In: j (1995).
[F1] x y. “a”. In: j (1990). 
Bar
[B2] x y. “d”. In: j (2005).
[B1] x y. “c”. In: j (2000).
```

Specifically, 1) order defined by order of `\nocite{a}` commands, OR reverse chronological order if that is not an option, 2) Filtered by keyword, 3) using `labelprefix`.

If someone can offer some code/advice to get the above functionality I would be grateful.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric,
sorting=none,
% sorting=ydnt  % prefer to sort manually w/ \nocite commands
backend=biber,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{b, author={x y}, title={b}, journal={j}, year=1995, keywords={foo}}
@article{a, author={x y}, title={a}, journal={j}, year=1990, keywords={foo}}
@article{c, author={x y}, title={c}, journal={j}, year=2000, keywords={bar}}
@article{d, author={x y}, title={d}, journal={j}, year=2005, keywords={bar}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\AtDataInput{%
  \csnumgdef{entrycount:\strfield{keywords}}{%
    \csuse{entrycount:\strfield{keywords}}+1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}    
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\csuse{entrycount:\strfield{keywords}}+1-#1\relax}

\begin{document}
Some text w/o citations.
% foo in reverse chronological order
\nocite{b} \nocite{a}
% bar in reverse chronological order
\nocite{d} \nocite{c}

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=F]
\printbibliography[keyword=foo, title=Foo]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=B]
\printbibliography[keyword=bar, title=Bar]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can generate your desired output with a couple of small changes. That said, I am not sure the solution is general enough for the real purpose. The changes are:

- Load `biblatex` with the `defernumbers` option
- Use `\jobname.bib` instead of `\jobname` as the bib resource (otherwise biber uses `\jobname.tex` as the bib resource
- Only step the `entrycount:*` value when `labelprefix` field is empty
- Define an `entrycount` for all keywords

The resulting MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric,
sorting=none,
% sorting=ydnt  % prefer to sort manually w/ \nocite commands
backend=biber,defernumbers,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{b, author={x y}, title={b}, journal={j}, year=1995, keywords={x, foo}}
@article{a, author={x y}, title={a}, journal={j}, year=1990, keywords={foo, x}}
@article{c, author={x y}, title={c}, journal={j}, year=2000, keywords={bar, y}}
@article{d, author={x y}, title={d}, journal={j}, year=2005, keywords={y, bar}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\define@key{blx@bib1}{keyword}{\xdef\mykeyword{#1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\stepKeywordCount}[1]{\csnumgdef{entrycount:#1}{\csuse{entrycount:#1}+1}}

\AtDataInput{%
  \iffieldundef{labelprefix}{%
    \begingroup%
      \edef\mytemp{\strfield{keywords}}
      \expandafter\forcsvlist\expandafter{\expandafter\stepKeywordCount\expandafter}\expandafter{\mytemp}%
    \endgroup%
  }{}%
}%

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{\number\numexpr\csuse{entrycount:\mykeyword}+1-#1\relax}
\newcommand{\mykeyword}{}

\begin{document}

Some text w/o citations.
% foo in reverse chronological order
\nocite{b} \nocite{a}
% bar in reverse chronological order
\nocite{d} \nocite{c}

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=F]
\printbibliography[keyword=foo, title=Foo]

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=B]
\printbibliography[keyword=bar, title=Bar]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, but perhaps my MWE wasn't complicated enough. It doesn't work if one of the keyword fields is changed to: `{foo, x}`. That better represents my actual `.bib` file.

Comment: @mankoff I think that is much more involved. What happens if the keyword is `{foo, bar}` and `{bar, foo}`?  Is the list of potential keywords known in advance?

Comment: Yes more advanced. This is very frustrating because this all worked fine in the <2016 version of TeXLive. Just to clarify, `keywords={foo,bar}` is two separate keywords, not one keyword with a comma.  Currently keyword list isn't known. If needed, I can simplify to one keyword per entry so that the MWE you posted works, but would rather not.

Comment: @mankoff see edits. You should edit your question to make it clearer what you want.