# Change labels in etaremune

Tags: lists, enumerate, etaremune

In the package `enumerate` I can set the label using `\begin{enumerate}[label={[\arabic*]}]`. However, if I try this in `etaremune` (provides a reverse list) I get the following error

- Package xkeyval Error: ``label' undefined in families `template'. \begin{etaremune}[label={[\arabic*]}]

How can I set the label in `etaremune`? The documentation tells me I can use the same labels, but it does not work for me. Below is an MWE that shows this issue.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}           % added for adjusting the indent of publications. adjusted locally at each list
\usepackage{etaremune}          % added for reverse numbering of enumerated lists
\begin{document}


  \section{A list with etaremune and label (returns an error)}
  \begin{etaremune}[label={[\arabic*]}]
    \item An item in a list
    \item An item in a list
    \item An item in a list
  \end{etaremune}


  \section{A list with enumerate and label (no error)}
  \begin{enumerate}[label={[\arabic*]}]
    \item An item in a list
    \item An item in a list
    \item An item in a list
  \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154300/4427 help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a reimplementation of `etaremune` using `enumitem`.

The idea is to set, at the end, a label that points to the last used number. This can be used for doing the necessary arithmetic with the help of `\getrefnumber`.

Two runs are obviously needed to get the counters in synch.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{refcount}

\makeatletter
\AddEnumerateCounter*{\reversearabic}{\@reversearabic}{2}
\newcommand{\reversearabic}[1]{\expandafter\@reversearabic\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\@reversearabic}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\getrefnumber{this@etaremune@\romannumeral\c@etaremune}-#1+1\relax
}
\newcounter{etaremune}
\newenvironment{etaremune}[1][]{%
  \stepcounter{etaremune}%
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\reversearabic*.,#1]%
}{%
  \edef\@currentlabel{\the\csname c@\@enumctr\endcsname}%
  \label{this@etaremune@\romannumeral\c@etaremune}%
  \end{enumerate}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={[\arabic*]}]
\item one
\item two
\item three
\item four
\end{enumerate}

\begin{etaremune}[label={[\reversearabic*]}]
\item one
\item two
\item three
\item four
\end{etaremune}

\begin{etaremune}
\item one
\item two
\item three
\item four
\end{etaremune}

\end{document}
```

[image]